# Univariate Normal Distribution Transformation

Tags: probability, statistics

X is the time taken for a high school athlete to complete a 100m sprint, in seconds, which follows a normal distribution with a mean of 16. The athlete would complete the sprint under 19.495 seconds 99% of the time. The amount of time the athlete rests in minutes before the next practice run is $$Y = 2\cdot e^{–\frac{X}{ 10}}$$.

I definitely understand well how to conduct univariate transformations. In this case one would integrate using upper-bound $-10\cdot ln(0.5Y)= X$. But with my experience, and mathematical ability, it would be extremely difficult to integrate the normal distribution function; can someone please assist me in the methodology involved in answering a question like this.

Is this where the lognormal distribution comes into play? How does one calculate the mean, variance and PDF for a lognormal function?

Comment: Lognormal is used when $Y=\ln X$ and $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

I´m not sure, if all requirements are met. I would do the following transformation:

$\begin{align}
F_Y(y) & =\mathsf P(X\leq x) & x= -10\ln(0.5\cdot y)
\\ & =\mathsf P\big(-10\cdot \ln(0.5\cdot Y)\leq -10\cdot \ln(0.5\cdot y)\big)
\\ & = \mathsf P\big(X\leq -10\cdot\ln(0.5\cdot y)\big)
\\ & =\Phi \left( \frac{-10\cdot\ln(0.5\cdot y)-\mu_x}{\sigma_x} \right)
\end{align}$

$X\sim \mathcal N(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2)$

$\Phi(\cdot )$ is the cummulative function of the standard normal distribution.